# Select the correct value per group based on multiple conditions (dplyr)

Tags: dplyr, conditional-statements

This is a variation of a question asked many times on here, but I cannot figure out my specific issue. I have the data frame below:

| SCR2. | name. |
| --- | --- |
| X. | Lobatus |
| X. | Panulirus |
| X. | Lutjanus |
| X. | Gerres |
| X. | Ocyurus |
| X. | Lutjanus |
| Y. | Gesmurros |
| Y. | Aricos |
| Y. | Plonks |
| Y. | Fibromos |
| Y. | Snarkae |
| Y. | Prontao |

Table: Table continues below

| RANK 1 | RANK 2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | NA |
| 2 | NA |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 3 |
| 5 | 2 |
| NA | NA |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 5 |
| 4 | 8 |
| 5 | 3 |
| NA | NA |

| RANK 3 |
| --- |
| NA |
| NA |
| 1 |
| 4 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 2 |
| 1 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 6 |
| 5 |

I would like to return 3 names from the 'name' column per group in 'SCR2' which have to abide by the following conditions:

- Name 1 needs to have the lowest possible rank (i.e. close to 1) in the 'RANK 1' column;
- Name 2 has to have the lowest possible rank (i.e. close to 1) in the 'RANK 2' column but cannot be the same name as Name 1;
- Name 3 has to have the lowest possible rank (i.e. close to 1) in the 'RANK 2' column but cannot be the same name as Name 1 or Name 2

In my example, I would like a data frame that returns 'Lobates' for name 1, 'Lutjanus' for name 2 and 'Ocyurus' for name 3 for X (in SCR2). I would like the data frame to return 'Gesmurros' as name 1, 'Aricos' as name 2 and 'Plonks' as name 3 for Y (in SCR2).

Hopefully that made sense. In the end, none of the 3 returned names should be the same.

I tried a method where I created a new column indicating overlaps, and then using dplyr to filter those out and select the minimum ranking number for each RANK per group, but it did not turn out as intended (still overlapping names between the ranks).

Comment: you mentioned you tried some code with dplyr, please provide an example

Comment: is that a typo in your question? Should it say "Name 3 has to have the lowest possible rank (i.e. close to 1) in the 'RANK 3' column but cannot be the same name as Name 1 or Name 2"

Comment: also, another question - do you need just the names, or is it important to you that for example, you have Name 1 assigned to Lobates, Name 2 to Lutjanus etc

Comment: Apologies that was indeed a typo; and I need just the names!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way of doing this would be using `dplyr::first()` and filtering out the undesired values for `name` for the following matches.

```r
library(dplyr)

base_df <- data.frame(
    SCR2 = c("X.","X.","X.","X.","X.",
           "X.","Y.","Y.","Y.","Y.","Y.","Y."),
    name = c("Lobatus","Panulirus",
           "Lutjanus","Gerres","Ocyurus","Lutjanus","Gesmurros",
           "Aricos","Plonks","Fibromos","Snarkae","Prontao"),
    RANK1 = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, NA, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, NA),
    RANK2 = c(NA, NA, 1L, 3L, 2L, NA, 1L, 2L, 5L, 8L, 3L, NA),
    RANK3 = c(NA, NA, 1L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 5L)
)

base_df |> 
    group_by(SCR2) |> 
    mutate(name1 = first(name, order_by = RANK1)) |> 
    filter(name != name1) |> 
    mutate(name2 = first(name, order_by = RANK2)) |> 
    filter(name != name2) |> 
    mutate(name3 = first(name, order_by = RANK3)) |> 
    ungroup() |> 
    distinct(SCR2, name1, name2, name3)
#> # A tibble: 2 × 4
#>   SCR2  name1     name2    name3  
#>   <chr> <chr>     <chr>    <chr>  
#> 1 X.    Lobatus   Lutjanus Ocyurus
#> 2 Y.    Gesmurros Aricos   Plonks
```

<sup>Created on 2023-10-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

You could also write a custom function to be used with `summarise()`, but it might not be worth the effort.